# How to force a file deletion on the server using System.IO.File.Delete?

Tags: c#, iis

Is it at all possible to delete a file programmatically from a website that was uploaded by the website, and that is in a locked state by using `System.IO.File.Delete`?

Comment: Do you know which process has a handle on the file and why?

Comment: I thought about that, but this will be running on a plesk host so I will not have access to manipulate the running tasks.The reason why is that I need to be able to remove old files that are not being used. For example uploading a new employee image to replace an old image. The old image will bean orphaned image and take up space until manually removed otherwise.